# Prove independent increments of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

There are many definitions of Brownian Motion and I am now working on the following:

> A collection of random variables $B : [0, ∞)×Ω → R$ is called a Brownian motion if
>
> (a) $B(·, ω)$ is continuous and $B(0, ω) = 0$ for any $ω ∈ Ω$
>
> (b) Any non-overlapping increments $B(a) − B(b)$, $B(c) − B(d)$ are independent, where $a < b ≤c < d$.
>
> (c) $B(t + s) − B(s) ∼ N (0, t)$ for any $t > 0, s ≥ 0$

Then I was asked to show that
$$B(t_1) − B(0), B(t_2) − B(t_1), · · · , B(t_n) − B(t_{n−1})$$ are independent.

This is weird since I believe that their (mutual) indenpendence are actually followed from the definition. So how should I start?

Comment: Actually the definition in your question still leaves something to prove since, for example, you are given that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are gaussian with $X$ independent of $Y+Z$ and $X+Y$ independent of $Z$ and you are asked to show that these conditions would imply that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Are you sure of the statement of (b)? What is your source?

Comment: @Did I just copied the definition from my assignment and it is difference from the refern\ence book. So confused about this question...

Comment: Wrong assignment then, most probably. Anyway, the implication in my comment, which one would need to solve this exercise, is not easy to prove and is probably false (I know, this formulation is weird, but I am sure you got the message...).